Sitefinity-Unable to complete the search indexing
On my local machine, I have set up an existing project running on Sitefinity 14.0.
When I try to re-index, it shows as in progress and never finishes.
I am able to browse the site and various pages without any issues.

How should I troubleshoot this issue?

do you have lots of pages to index? are there any errors in the logs?
